# update ng-repeat when data in service updates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I have a message service that stores any messages that need to be displayed to the user like this

```
app.controller('messageCtrl', function($scope, messages){
    //what to do
});

app.factory('messages', function(){
    return {
        messages: [
            {type:'info', text: 'info Message'},
            {type:'success', text: 'success Message'},
            {type:'warning', text: 'warning Message'},
            {type:'danger', text: 'danger Message'}
        ],

        addMessage: function(message){
            messages.push(message);
        },

        getMessages: function(){
            return messages;
        }
    };
);
```

what do I need to do in my controller to be able to ng-repeat the content of messages and have it update whenever another controller adds a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.controller('messageCtrl', function($scope, messages){
    $scope.localMessages = messages.messages;
    //Just be sure to not replace the original array and this will work
    //if you need to repopulate the array or empty it use angular.copy()
});

app.factory('messages', function(){
    return {
        messages: [
            {type:'info', text: 'info Message'},
            {type:'success', text: 'success Message'},
            {type:'warning', text: 'warning Message'},
            {type:'danger', text: 'danger Message'}
        ],

    addMessage: function(message){
        messages.push(message);
    },

    getMessages: function(){
        return messages;
        }
    };
);
```

Comment: i feel stupid, forgot that arrays are passed by reference instead of copied. So as long as my original array is not destroyed or replaced any updates should be visible on the copy.

Comment: Easy to forget, the watches on the scope on your controller should see the changes though as you said so long as the same object is persisted and not replaced in the service (this is another gotcha lots of people stumble on).